# I want to randomly display divs - how do I do this?

Tags: javascript, html

I've followed a tutorial to create a random quote generator (using an array of quotes), and this works fine.

I've then tried to create the same random generator but rather than displaying inner html from an array of quotes, I want to get it to display divs, inside which I have placed iframes with different content.

This didn't work, and in the console it kept saying that the onclick button wasn't defined.

Can anyone tell me how I even begin to do this? I am completely new to Javascript and have mainly been pulling bits of code from other places to try to see how it works.

Basically, I want a button that when clicked displays a random div. I would also like the button text to change once it's been clicked once - so if anyone can help me with how I can do that too that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add your code which didn't worked ?

Comment: Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: Isn't it better to randomly load innerHTML for a single `div`, rather than showing a random `div` and hiding many others?

Comment: I'm completely new to this: how do I add my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your approach you need to loop through elements and set style `display: block` (visible) to a random element, while hiding others with style `display: none`.

Here's a complete example:

```js
var w = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var button = document.getElementById('randomize');
var quotes = w.children; // inner elements, your quotes divs

// a function to hide all divs
var hideDivs = function(divs) {
  for (var div of divs) {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

hideDivs(quotes); // hide all initially

// on click
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length); // get random index
  hideDivs(quotes); // hide all quotes
  quotes[rnd].style.display = 'block'; // show random quote
  event.target.textContent = 'Click one more time!'; // set button text. event.target is the button you've clicked
})
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="quote">Chuck Norris counted to infinity... Twice.</div>
  <div class="quote">Chuck Norris has already been to Mars; that's why there are no signs of life there.</div>
  <div class="quote">Guns don't kill people. Chuck Norris kills People.</div>
  <div class="quote">There is no theory of evolution. Just a list of animals Chuck Norris allows to live.</div>
  <div class="quote">Chuck Norris uses pepper spray to spice up his steaks.</div>
</div>
<button id='randomize'>Randomize</button>
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this! When I pasted this in to my text editor and ran the code on my page the divs were all displayed rather than hidden though?

Comment: Ah, now it works! Thanks for this, really appreciate it.

Comment: @t1337 you're welcome. Consider accepting this answer if it answers your question.